# Changed ISP to DSL and now certain websites won't load (Xubuntu 16.10)

Tags: networking, xubuntu, internet, 16.10, dsl

I recently switched ISPs from cable to DSL, and now certain websites (such as twitch.tv and gamestop.com) will either not load properly or not at all.  Twitch won't let me login (just about everything else there works), and Gamestop won't load at all.  I have tried various browsers (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, Pale Moon) with the same results.

These sites load fine on my Windows PC on the same network, and they also load fine in a VM running Xubuntu on my Windows PC.  The PC having issues is running Xubuntu 16.10, but the same version of Xubuntu had no issues loading websites through a VM on my Windows PC.

I am behind a router that is taking care of the PPPoe login and such, so I don't think that's the issue.  I have DHCP turned off on my router, and all of my devices are setup to use static IPs.  I use Google's DNS servers on all of my devices.  I'm about to do a full reinstall to try and fix this, but I figured I'd ask for help here first.  If there's any information I've left out, feel free to ask for it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If it was working before the ISP switch, I would not be looking at Ubuntu as the source of the issues.  If all browsers don't work for a site, then start by ruling out your computer as the source of a problem by testing other systems on the network.  Are those able to reach those sites?

Comment: Yes, I said above that my Windows PC loads these websites just fine and a VM running Xubuntu 16.10 on that PC also loads these websites :-\...

I'm not sure what would be the issue with this specific PC; I have changed no settings since the ISP switch.  I'm not trying to blame Ubuntu.  I just don't really know where else to ask for help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting my MTU value down to 1300.  I tried using 1492 (the value my ISP gave) previously, but that didn't work.  I read a few posts suggesting to go down to 1300, and now all sites seem to load.